# PHP bound parameters database call wrong number of parameters if I use a colon

Tags: php, mysql

```
        $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT users.userID,fname,lname,status FROM users INNER JOIN friends ON users.userID = friends.friendID WHERE friends.userID = ? AND ((friends.status LIKE 'group%' OR friends.status = 'friends') OR (users.status = '?') OR (users.userID = ?)) ORDER BY friends.status,lname,fname ASC");
    $sth->execute(array($_SESSION['userID'],'sub:'.$_SESSION['userID'],$_SESSION['userID']));
```

In the above code, you can see that I have a prepare statement with a query. In that query, I have three question marks for variable substitution. In the execute statement, I provide variables. Last I checked, I can count to three, but PHP disagrees. I keep getting "Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens" for the line where the execute is.

I thought it might be related to the colon in the second parameter so I pulled that out, but it did the same thing. I even pulled out the string concatenation and just left the userID and I got the same thing.

Either it's really late or there's some voodoo going on here. Any insights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `'?'` is not a placeholder, it is a literal question mark. Placeholders don't get quoted. As is you have two placeholders, and three values attempted to be bound.

So try:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT users.userID,fname,lname,status FROM users INNER JOIN friends ON users.userID = friends.friendID WHERE friends.userID = ? AND ((friends.status LIKE 'group%' OR friends.status = 'friends') OR (users.status = ?) OR (users.userID = ?)) ORDER BY friends.status,lname,fname ASC");
```

Comment: THANK YOU. That was driving me crazy and I don't know if I would have figured it out even if I hadn't been so tired last night. So we have to count on PHP to insert them intelligently. So be it.