# PDO prepare insert values

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I try to insert the data from my form (createBuilder) into my Database, using PDO and a custom prepare request:

```
public function createUser($data)
{
    $connect = $this->connectBDD();

    $rq = " INSERT INTO user (email, password, firstname, lastname, salt, role, addf, addl)
            VALUES (:email, :password, :firstname, :lastname, :salt, :role, NULL, NULL)";

    $t  = $connect->prepare($rq);
    $t->execute([
        ':email'     => $data["email"],
        ':password'  => $data["plainPassword"],
        ':firstname' => $data["firstname"],
        ':lastname'  => $data["lastname"],
        ':salt'      => $data["salt"],
        ':role'      => 'ROLE_USER'
    ]);

    return true;
}
```

But I get the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERREUR: erreur de syntaxe sur ou près de « user »
>       LINE 1: INSERT INTO user (email, password, firstname, lastname, sal...
>       ^

Is this because of the two 'NULL' last values ? I don't think so because if I add 2 more variables into my array, I still get the error...

Thanks for help

Comment: Placeholders are values without `'`. Please refer to PDO manual. Do you see there any placeholders wrapped in `'`?

Comment: Answered similar yesterday, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38548317/php-bound-parameters-database-call-wrong-number-of-parameters-if-i-use-a-colon/3

Comment: But without the ' like VALUES (:email, :password, :firstname, :lastname, :salt, :role, NULL, NULL), I got a "SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERREUR: erreur de syntaxe sur ou près de « user »"

Comment: What does that say? Update the question with error, and code.

Comment: Shouldn't be there a standard answer for such kinds of questions?

Comment: @u_mulder I don't know of one so I flagged as one that is almost the same, just dynamic placeholder rather than named.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`':email'` is a string with the characters `:`, `e`, `m`, etc... `:email` (WITHOUT the `'`) is a placeholder.

Placeholders should never be quoted - quoting them turns into not-placeholders.

```
$sql = "... VALUES(:email, :password, :firstname,  etc...";
```

Comment: Ok for the quotes @Marc, but without I still have an error. I've updated the question

Comment: It is not a reserved word) Keyword yes, but not reserved.

Comment: ah yeah. I keep missing the `[R]` in there... 'course, OP hasn't specified that they are using mysql, so who knows. maybe it is some other db where user is reserved.

Comment: I update the table name into "users", now I got a SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table "users"...